# Rendering comma separated list of links

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to output a list of comma separated links and this is my solution.

```
var Item = React.createComponent({
  render: function() {

    var tags = [],
        tag;

    for (var i = 0, l = item.tags.length; i < l; i++) {
      if (i === item.tags.length - 1) {
        tag = <span><Tag key={i} tag={item.tags[i]} /></span>;
      } else {
        tag = <span><Tag key={i} tag={item.tags[i]} /><span>, </span></span>;
      }
      tags.push(tag);
    }

    return (
      <tr>
        <td>
          {item.name}
        </td>
        <td>
          {tags}
        </td>
      </tr>
    );

  }
});
```

I was just wondering if there was a better, more clean way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 77, accepted):

At Khan Academy we use a helper called `intersperse` for this:

```js
/* intersperse: Return an array with the separator interspersed between
 * each element of the input array.
 *
 * > _([1,2,3]).intersperse(0)
 * [1,0,2,0,3]
 */
function intersperse(arr, sep) {
    if (arr.length === 0) {
        return [];
    }

    return arr.slice(1).reduce(function(xs, x, i) {
        return xs.concat([sep, x]);
    }, [arr[0]]);
}
```

which allows you to write code like:

```
var tags = item.tags.map(function(tag, i) {
    return <Tag key={i} tag={item.tags[i]} />;
};
tags = intersperse(tags, ", ");
```

Comment: Any idea how you could pass an element (like a `<span/>`) as the second parameter? It does work, but I get a warning about not specifying a key... I tried by wrapping the `<span>` in a function (and generate a random key) but that doesn't seem very correct or to work.

Comment: I just realised this is the way I could do it; pass a function as the separator that accepts and idx and then use the index of the array reducer as a key.

Comment: Something like in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/thomasjonas/f99f48e278fd2dfe82edb2c6f7d6c365)

Answer (score 120):

**Simply**

```jsx
{tags.map((tag, i) => <span key={i}>
    {i > 0 && ", "}
    <Tag tag={tag} />
</span>)}
```

In React 16 it can be done even more simpler:

```jsx
{tags.map((tag, i) => [
    i > 0 && ", ",
    <Tag key={i} tag={tag} />
])}
```

Comment: Sweet and Simple!

Comment: @imos Would you mind explaining this a bit? `{!!i && ", "}`

Comment: @Macxim This line prints comma before each tag except first. Expression `!!i` just converts `i` to boolean. Also `!!i` can be replaced by `i > 0`.

Comment: @imos Thank you very much.

Comment: One of the best value-per-character answers, I've ever seen. Should I propose migrating this to Code Golf? =)

Comment: Will this append a comma after 1st element as well? The reason I'm asking, for the 1st element, index will be `o` and `!!0` will return `false`. Also I think this should add an additional comma after the last element.

Comment: @Abhijith At each iteration it thinks "Should i add comma *before* this item?". At 1st iteration it thinks "should i add comma at the very begining?". If we erase `!!i &&` it renders `<span>, 0</span><span>, 1</span> ...`.

Comment: Oh my mistake.. I was reading this as: 
`{tags.map((tag, i) => <React.Fragment key={i}>
    <Tag tag={tag} />
    {!!i && ", "}
</React.Fragment>)}
`

Comment: what's the use of the square brackets in the second example? `=> [...]`

Comment: @kenold Square brackets is just an array. Function returns an array of two ellements: comma string and react element. Whole `tags.map(...)` returns list of such pairs. React unwraps resulting nested set of arrays into flat list like `<Tag/>", "<Tag/>", " <Tag/>", " <Tag/>` and then renders it

Comment: @imos - Got it! thanks - I just used this on a Gatsby project.

Comment: Not sweet and not simple. Actually, this is way more complicated that it should be IMHO. Understood, though.

Comment: If there was a way to give "gold" (Reddit-style) on SO, this answer would get it from me. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

Or simply write the list items to an unordered list and use CSS.

```
var Item = React.createComponent({
  render: function() {

    var tags = this.props.item.tags.map(function(i, item) {
      return <li><Tag key={i} tag={item} /></li>
    });

    return (
      <tr>
        <td>
          {this.props.item.name}
        </td>
        <td>
          <ul className="list--tags">
            {tags}
          </ul>
        </td>
      </tr>
    );

  }
});
```

And the CSS:

```
.list--tags {
    padding-left: 0;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

.list--tags > li {
    display: inline;
}

.list--tags > li:before {
    content:',\0000a0'; /* Non-breaking space */
}
.list--tags > li:first-child:before {
    content: normal;
}
```

Comment: It's really not explicit this way

Comment: I like this approach. I just used `.csv` class and make it work with any element: `.csv>*`, not just `ui>li` and it's perfectly understandable

Comment: I like this approach because it's semantic, and as far as I can tell works better for accessibility.

Answer (score 3):

```
import React from 'react';
import { compact } from 'lodash';

// Whatever you want to separate your items with commas, space, border...
const Separator = () =>  { ... }; 

// Helpful component to wrap items that should be separated
const WithSeparators = ({ children, ...props }) => {

  // _.compact will remove falsey values: useful when doing conditional rendering
  const array = compact(React.Children.toArray(children));

  return array.map((childrenItem, i) => (
    <React.Fragment key={`${i}`}>
      {i > 0 && <Separator {...props} />}
      {childrenItem}
    </React.Fragment>
  ));
};

const MyPage = () => (
  <WithSeparators/>
    <div>First</div>
    {second && (<div>Maybe second</div>)}
    {third && (<div>Maybe third</div>)}
    <div>Fourth</div>
  </WithSeparators>
);
```

Answer (score 2):

A function component that does the trick. Inspired by @imos's response. Works for React 16.

```
const Separate = ({ items, render, separator = ', ' }) =>
  items.map((item, index) =>
    [index > 0 && separator, render(item)]
  )

<Separate
  items={['Foo', 'Bar']}
  render={item => <Tag tag={item} />}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that allows `<span>`s and `<br>`s and junk as the separator:

```
const createFragment = require('react-addons-create-fragment');

function joinElements(arr,sep=<br/>) {
    let frag = {};
    for(let i=0,add=false;;++i) {
        if(add) {
            frag[`sep-${i}`] = sep;
        }
        if(i >= arr.length) {
            break;
        }
        if(add = !!arr[i]) {
            frag[`el-${i}`] = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return createFragment(frag);
}
```

It filters out falsey array elements too. I used this for formatting addresses, where some address fields are not filled out.

It uses fragments to avoid the warnings about missing keys.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the great answers above Ramda has [intersperse](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#intersperse).

To comma separate a bunch of items you could do:

```
const makeLinks = (x: Result[]) =>
  intersperse(<>,</>, map(makeLink, x))
```

Pretty succinct

Answer (score 0):

**The solution without extra tags**

```
<p className="conceps inline list">
  {lesson.concepts.flatMap((concept, i) =>
    [concept, <span key={i} className="separator">&#8226;</span>]
  , ).slice(-1)}
</p>
```

generates something like

**Function • Function type • Higher-order function • Partial application**

Answer (score 0):

Simple one:

```
{items.map((item, index) => (
    <span key={item.id}>
      {item.id}
      {index < items.length - 1 && ', '}
    </span>
 ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do

```
const elementsArr = ["a", "b", "c"];
let elementsToRender = [] ;
elementsArr.forEach((element, index) => {
    let elementComponent = <TAG className="abc" key={element.id}>{element}</TAG>
    elementsToRender.push(elementComponent);
    if(index !== (elementsArr.length - 1)){
        elementsToRender.push(", ");
    }
});

render(){
    return (
        <div>{elementsToRender}</div>
    )
}
```