# CSS selector and content property to add a space character between two inline-block elements

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element, css-content

I have a series of `span` elements of class `tag` (from bootstrap v4) which are adjacent to each other without any space between them because they come from a reacj.js array of JSX elements :

```
<span class="tag tag-primary">text</span><span class="tag tag-primary">text</span><!-- ... -->
```

This is the CSS from bootstrap:

```
.tag {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.25em 0.4em;
    font-size: 75%;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
}
```

These elements can wrap over several lines in a table cell. I could add a space character in-between painfully with some javascript (https://stackoverflow.com/a/23619085/3446439), or add a wrapping element (to have only one root element in the JSX) with a space character. Both these options don't satisfy me and I figured it should be simple to do it in CSS.

I tried the following, which would be ideal if it worked, but it doesn't with inline-block elements (https://jsfiddle.net/qjbgzzLr/) :

```
span.tag + span.tag::before {
    content: " ";
}
```

For now, I put a `margin-left` on `span.tag + span.tag` but this is **not ideal** since the first element in every line has a margin to its left.

Is there a way to achieve this with **CSS only** ?

Comment: Looks like the pseudo-element solution works to me - https://jsfiddle.net/vassuvw4/

Comment: Pseudo-element solution doesn't work with bootstrap https://jsfiddle.net/qjbgzzLr/ Will edit question

Comment: So you do have those blue boxes around your text and you would like to have a space between them?

Comment: Yes, I would like to have a space between them, but only if they are adjacent on the same line of text.

Comment: Found out the pseudo-element doesn't work because it is `inline-block`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any pseudo-element would be inside the span tag and so would not create a horizontal space between tags. Margin is the only solution available to you.

I'd suggest just adding margin-*right* to each tag.

```
span.tag {
  margin-right: .25em;
}
```

```css
span.tag {
  margin-right: .25em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<span class="tag tag-primary">text</span><span class="tag tag-primary">text</span><span class="tag tag-primary">text</span><span class="tag tag-primary">text</span><span class="tag tag-primary">text</span><span class="tag tag-primary">text</span><span
class="tag tag-primary">text</span><span class="tag tag-primary">text</span><span class="tag tag-primary">text</span><span class="tag tag-primary">text</span><span class="tag tag-primary">text</span><span class="tag tag-primary">text</span><span class="tag tag-primary">text</span><span
  class="tag tag-primary">text</span><span class="tag tag-primary">text</span><span class="tag tag-primary">text</span><span class="tag tag-primary">text</span><span class="tag tag-primary">text</span><span class="tag tag-primary">text</span><span class="tag tag-primary">text</span><span
    class="tag tag-primary">text</span>
```

To remove the margin from the final tag you can use

```
span:last-of-type {
margin-right:0;
}
```

Comment: Alright, will accept this as answer if you add `:last-of-type` with a `margin-right` of 0

Comment: OK..but it's not really necessaryfor the answer to work.

Comment: In fact, for it to be exactly identical to adding a space between the `span`'s, there should also be no right margin for the last element of each line. This is not so important in this case, but here the margin will count towards the length of the line when calculating line-breaks, where it would not if it were a space character. (correct me if I'm wrong)