# Rendering Comma separated links in React with word wrap

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, firefox

I am trying to render links from a list. Everything works fine until my links goes to next line.

```
const relatedLink = _.map(personList, (person, index) => {
        const comma = index
            ? <span>,&nbsp;</span>
            : null;

        return (
            <span key={"key_" + person.name}
                  className="related-names-link">
            {comma}
                <NameLink
                    personId= {orderIdAndNumber.orderId}
                    key={"person_link_" + person.name}>
                    {person.name}
                </NameLink>
            </span>
        );
    });

    <div className="related-names-links">
         {relatedLink}
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.related-names-links {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
```

When the list goes big the comma for the first line last name goes to next line, instead of this I want the comma to stay in first line itself.

Actual Result:

```
Jack, Tom, Jerry
, Mickey, Donald, Flintstone
```

Expected Result:

```
Jack, Tom, Jerry,
Mickey, Donald, Flintstone
```

I tried with the answers from [Rendering comma separated list of links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23618744/rendering-comma-separated-list-of-links) but still I'm getting the same output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your span content pattern is `, <name>`, it should be `<name>,`. move `{comma}` after `NameLink`, and for comma validation check if `index < personList.length - 1`.

Comment: Great Works as expected.